# django "use_natural_foreign_keys=True" issue

Tags: sql, django, model

I currently use the well documented "use_natural_foreign_keys=True" to return the relevant field data required instead of the id:

```
all_orders = Orders.objects.all()
resp = serializers.serialize('json', all_orders, use_natural_foreign_keys=True)
```

What I don't know how to do is return both the id AND the field data required as typically returned by the "use of use_natural_foreign_keys=True".

Anyone know of a quick fix to return both?

Many thanks, Alan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

define a "natural_key" method in your model class, whose id and field_name you like to get. e.g

```
def natural_key(self):
    return (self.id, self.field_name)
```